# i get this error when i try to use Future builder and snapshot even the Json File is ok

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, snapshot

[image: future builder not work and receive null value even I test my PHP file and everything is ok]

the value return null I don not know why that I  test The Function getnote() also it give me "fail"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost surely the first snapshot will contain do data because the future is still running. Check if the snapshot has data, and also check for errors:

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
    // now you can be sure that snapshot.data is not null
  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
    // manage errors
  }
  // otherwise show a progress indicator while the future is running
  return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
}
```

Comment: still not work for me i thing the future builder work without waiting the function getnotes()

Comment: Maybe you should add the return type, like `FutureBuilder<your type>`, and your future function should be declared like `Future<your type> getnotes() async {...}`.

Comment: Also it is a good practice not the add the function directly because it will re-run on every build. Check [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).